# Is Adiel Tel-Oren an MD?

Tags: celebrities

Adiel Tel-Oren (aka Dr. T.) is, according to his [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/doctorteloren/)

> a renowned holistic scientist, author, innovator, & educator.

His Facebook page also claims he is an MD and DC.

His company's [web-page](http://www.ecopolitan.com/doctor-t) goes further about that degree:

> After several years of successful practice as a nutrition and functional medicine physician, he returned to school and received his Medical Diploma (MD) at the prestigious Pirogov Medical University (Russia's flagship medical institute, which placed 3rd in UNESCO's competition for the world's best medical school).
>
> [...]
>
> M.D. : Medicine, 1996 - Pirogovo Medical Institute - Russian State Medical University Russia; Completed clinical rotations at several hospitals and clinics in the USA in addition to the many University hospitals and forensic medicine centers in Moscow.

However [The Jerusalem Post](https://www.jpost.com/Health-and-Science/Health-Ministry-warns-public-against-imposter-posing-as-physician-353113) warned in 2014 (and [2015](https://www.jpost.com/Breaking-News/Health-Ministry-Man-without-an-MD-license-continues-to-treat-patients-402630)) that he's an impostor.

> The Health Ministry issued a warning yesterday about a man named Adiel Tel-Oren who presents himself as a physician but is an imposter.
>
> He is “unlicensed to practice medicine in Israel. He treats patients in his clinic while using preparations that are liable to endanger health and are not approved for use,” the ministry said on Thursday.
>
> The ministry says that Tel Oren “admitted to us while he was taped that he is not a licensed medical doctor,” that he is not recognized as an MD in either Israel or the US and that the authorities suspect his studies’ diploma from Russia is “counterfeit.”

I haven't found anything definitive, only [some people commenting at greatnonprofits.org](http://greatnonprofits.org/org/ecopolitan-eco-health-community-university-of-natural-medicine)

He continues to [offer medical services](http://archive.is/6VjmR#https://www.eventbrite.com/e/skin-clinic-in-oak-park-il-tickets-50594919767) and [claim to be an MD *and* DC](https://web.archive.org/web/20220328102857/https://naturalexpo.org/schedule-list.html) as of 2021.

Comment: If you don't believe the Israeli Health Ministry, what kind of evidence _would_ you believe?

Comment: Israeli Health Ministry didn't speak definitively to him being an MD, just to him not being licensed to practice in Israel.  I think he works mainly in the US.

You didn't think to put "Adiel Tel-Oren" in the search box on facebook? It brings up [an entry](https://www.facebook.com/doctorteloren/) marked "Public Figure" in blue; also has a blue checkmark.

Why are you attacking the sources I gave in my QUESTION?  It's a question, not an answer.  It's perfectly normal to have iffy sources in a question.

Comment: The Health Ministry says _that he is not recognized as an MD in either Israel or the US and that the authorities suspect his studies’ diploma from Russia is “counterfeit.”_ His website lists him doing all kinds of other stuff in the US during the time that he was supposedly getting an MD in Russia. He admits on his own website that he gave up his chiropractor's license in US, apparently to avoid these [misconduct proceedings](http://web.archive.org/web/20120227085216/http://www.mn-chiroboard.state.mn.us/Orders/SO%20Tel-Oren,%20Adiel%2009%2004%2009.pdf). Again, what more are you looking for?

Comment: "authorities suspect his studies’ diploma from Russia is “counterfeit" . Operative word is *suspect*.  Is it or isn't it?  My best guess is that if it is, he's not an MD, and if it isn't, he is.  And perhaps what constitutes an MD is not what I think it is.  These are what I'm looking for clarification on.

Comment: Also, JPost seems to have changed its tune; the piece by BARRY DAVIS \  05/28/2016  says he's a qualified medical doctor. (Most of it requires registration to see, but not that bit.)

Comment: @MatthewElvey: Have you a link? Shoud that be an answer?

Comment: A photo caption referring to him as a "qualified medical doctor" doesn't mean that the newspaper "changed its tune", just that some writer there didn't do any digging while writing a fluff piece about an event. Israel's health ministry has warned people about him twice: [here](http://www.health.gov.il/English/News_and_Events/Spokespersons_Messages/Pages/22052014_1.aspx), [here](http://www.health.gov.il/English/News_and_Events/Spokespersons_Messages/Pages/10052015_1.aspx).

Comment: Anyways, verifying someone's degree seems to be outside the scope of this site, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: I'm planning on deleting the question tomorrow.  If you want a copy, please take and reuse my contributions w/o attribution.  More on fb: https://www.facebook.com/events/1628801244105849/ and https://www.facebook.com/imposterPosingAsPhysician/?fref=ts

Comment: This should be a red-flag: "_Medical Diploma_ (MD)" - that is not what the generally accepted MD means in terms of medicine https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Medicine (even in Russia, the title is _Doctor of Medicine_)

Comment: Why delete it? We now have a decent question and it's getting interest.

Comment: If it helps, relevant links are: [Quack watch](https://quackwatch.org/cases/board/chiro/tel-oren/surrender_2009/), and the Israeli Ministry of Health warnings [2014](https://www.health.gov.il/English/News_and_Events/Spokespersons_Messages/Pages/22052014_1.aspx) and [2015](https://www.health.gov.il/English/News_and_Events/Spokespersons_Messages/Pages/10052015_1.aspx).  A lengthy comment purportedly by Dr T is [here](https://greatnonprofits.org/org/ecopolitan-eco-health-community-university-of-natural-medicine), which says "I never told ANYONE in Israel or the USA that I am a licensed MD there."

Comment: I see 4 comments there, but none like that, none containing any of the words [never anyone Israel].  Taken down?  (The 3 documents are indirectly linked already, but more links/sources are good.)

Comment: It's a lengthy comment at the bottom of [this page](https://greatnonprofits.org/org/ecopolitan-eco-health-community-university-of-natural-medicine) and you need to click "Comments ( 1 )" to see it.  It begins "clinic 04/30/2016 To Health-Minded Individuals and Scientists Who Know better Than To Believe Everything They See In the Media or Promoted by the ...".  (I copy/pasted it to Pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/6g1RtnNA).)

Answer (score 3):

Under US law, he is not a medical doctor.  He is not licensed to practice medicine in the U.S.  Under the headline

"*Minneapolis skin clinic operator is practicing medicine without license, state regulators say*",
 the Star Tribune newspaper [reported in 2019](https://www.startribune.com/minneapolis-skin-clinic-operator-is-practicing-medicine-without-license-state-regulators-say/564556822/):

> An unlicensed physician who calls himself “Dr. T” is illegally removing moles and providing other improper services at a Minneapolis clinic and dozens of other sites around the country, according to a lawsuit that two state agencies have filed.

It goes on:

> **Tel-Oren acknowledged he is not licensed to practice medicine in the United States.** He said his medical license allows him to work only in Russia.

> In the lawsuit, the Medical Board said Tel-Oren is not allowed to advertise himself as a medical doctor unless he has the proper license.

But he continues to [claim to be an MD *and* DC in advertising](https://web.archive.org/web/20220328102857/https://naturalexpo.org/schedule-list.html) and on his facebook page, as of 2022.

This is on top of [the Jerusalem Post article](https://www.jpost.com/health-and-science/health-ministry-warns-public-against-imposter-posing-as-physician-353113) discussed above.